# Perl 6 one-liner to print unique lines of a file

Tags: raku

I've found this very useful one-liner, it works, but I can't understand how it manages to cycle through the lines of the file twice.

```
perl6 -ne 'state %l; .say if ++%l{$_} == 1' input-file.txt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is only one cycle.
It collects all of the lines as keys in `%l`, with the values being the number of times it has seen it.
If this is the first time (`… == 1`) it has come across a copy of the current line it prints it.

It basically works the same as:

```perl6
my %l;

for $*ARGFILES.lines() {  # this is basically what `-n` does

  ++%l{ $_ };             # update the count

  .say if %l{ $_ } == 1;  # print it if this is the first time it was seen

}
```

I think the reason `… if ++$… == 1` was used instead of `… unless $…++` is that [`&prefix:«++»`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#prefix_++) is slightly more performant than [`&postfix:«++»`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#postfix_++)

---

Another potentially more efficient (depending on the implementation of [`.unique`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/unique)) way to write it would be:

```sh
perl6 -e '.put for $*ARGFILES.lines.unique' input-file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! I misunderstood the logic, though it's indeed very simple.

Comment: No need to call lines on `$*ARGFILES`, if you call just `lines()` it'll already operate on `$*ARGFILES`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's unpack this is a bit. The `-n` option adds a `for lines() { ... }` loop around the code, so we have

```
for lines() { 
    state %l;
    .say if ++%l{$_} == 1
}
```

Why a `state` var? There is no easy way to declare a variable in an outer scope of the implicit loop of that one line. Otherwise you'd write that as

```
my %l;
for lines() { 
    .say if ++%l{$_} == 1
}
```

`%l` keeps track of the number of times a line (stored in `$_`) has been seen. It uses autovification, so the first time a line is seen, the `++` operator automatically adds it to the hash.

`.say` is a shorthand for `$_.say`

Comment: Thanks! What do `()` after `lines` mean?

Comment: That `lines` doesn't take any arguments.  This is needed in this situation because otherwise the `{ }` would be taken as an argument to the `lines` sub.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a more readable Raku one-liner to get rid of duplicate lines:

```
raku -e 'lines.unique.join("\n").put;' input-file.txt
```

Briefly, neither the `-n` nor the `-p` commandline flags are set:  input is read using `lines`. The `unique` command is used to make lines unique. Since `lines` auto-chomps trailing newlines, the output is `join`-ed back together with `join("\n")`, to return linewise output.

ALTERNATIVELY:

```
raku -e '.unique.join("\n").put given lines;' input-file.txt
```

Above the `given` topicalizer is used. According to the docs: *"`given` can follow a statement to set the topic in the statement it follows."* Again, neither the `-n` nor the `-p` commandline flags are set: input is read using `lines`.

https://docs.raku.org/syntax/given